# What matrices would not be in a linear space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to learn linear algebra and saw the term linear space, which is given below:
[image]

The definition seems broad, but oddly also specific, as matrices within the linear space must be linear combinations of other matrices or a matrix as a result of scalar multiplication.

So given a linear space of mxn matrices, what kind of mxn matrix would NOT exist in that space.  Is it possible, just mathematically, that k*A and A + B do not produce all possible mxn matrices?  The weird definition makes it seem that way.  Why not just define the linear space as all real mxn matrices?  Basically $R^{mn}$?

The reason why that definition seems weird, is because later on, the author qualifies every formula by saying the matrices or vectors need to belong in the same linear space.
[image]

It seems weird that distances only apply to matrices within the same linear space, (assuming a linear space does not include all mxn matrices) as the distance is just the sumproduct of values and has nothing to do with linear combinations.

He doesn't mention how to calculate the distance between two matrices if they are not in the same linear space...

Answer (score 1):

A linear space need not contain all possible matrices, it can be a subspace. As usual in vector spaces, it is the set of elements spanned by a basis.

For instance

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&a-b\\b&0\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$ is a linear space.

Comment: Is there a difference between calculating the distance between two matrices in a linear space and two matrices that are not?

Comment: @confused : no.

Comment: Thanks.  So why, for every formula, he says, for "two nonnull vectors in a linear space" or "two nonnull matrices in a linear space", as opposed to just leaving linear space out?

Comment: @confused: because the text is about linear spaces.